# Providing File permissions in Installshield

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

1. I have created an installer in **Installshield X**.
2. I want to give '**write permissions**' to few files when the installation is done in **Non-Admin Windows accounts** ( by default it will have only 'read' permission).
3. If I select individual file and go to properties (inside Installshield),i have permissions tab where they have provided options like Domain , Readonly, Full Control, Modify etc. I have tested these options but it doesn't effect the msi file.(specific files doesn't have write permission). Is there something wrong I am doing?
4. There is another way of doing this, writing the script

```vb
Set objShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
installDir = Session.Property("INSTALLDIR.5A884667_3CC4_41EC_B0F2_BEEAB457BB8C")
supportDir = Session.Property("SUPPORTDIR")
length = Len(installDir) 
lastChar = Right(installDir, 1)
if (lastChar = "\") Then
    installDir = Left(installDir, length - 1)
end if
   'MsgBox supportDir & "\setacl.exe """ & installDir & """ /dir /set S-1-5-32-545      /full /p:yes /sid /silent"
   objshell.Run supportDir & "\setacl.exe """ & installDir & """ /dir /set S-1-5-32-545 /full /p:yes /sid /silent",0,true
```

Can someone please explain me what is going on here? those last set s-1-5-32-545.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can author the [**MsiLockPermissionEx table**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408009(v=vs.85).aspx), though you should not apply such custom permissions to the installation folder at all. Rather you should have the application store your settings files in the user profile or in HKCU in the registry.

- [Setting Permissions in Windows Installer: MSILockPermissionsEX and ISLockPermissions](http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2010/11/setting-permissions-in-windows-installer-msilockpermissionsex-and-islockpermissions.html#sthash.8AwB4UwT.dpuf).
- [Tutorial: How to Use the MsiLockPermissionsEx Table](http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/csigetsddlfromobject)
- [Securing Files, Folders, Registry Keys, and Windows Services in a Locked-Down Environment](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield18helplib/SecurityPermissions.htm)